# Not able to use Current_timestamp as default value in mysql 5.5.47-cll

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am not able to set `Current_timestamp` as default value. My `Mysql` version is `5.5.47`.

Query is

```
ALTER TABLE `downloads` ADD `date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

[image]

While it is working fine on my local DB with `mysql V5.6.56`.

Comment: `datetime` with default as current time stamp is allowed since mysql v-5.6.. before that its only `timestamp`  datatype can have current timestamp as default.

Comment: is there any way to do this in `v5.5`

Comment: in v-5.5 you can use `timestamp` datatype instead of `datetime` to support default

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty : Thanks, its worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE downloads CHANGE `date`  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

And if you are adding a new column with default time then

```
ALTER TABLE `downloads` ADD `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ;
```

Comment: When I run this query nothing happen. phpmyadmin just loading.

Comment: @urfusion:- Is the `date` column already present in the table?

Comment: @urfusion:- Try this: `ALTER TABLE downloads add` ``date``  `TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` I thought you are changing the column.

Comment: @urfusion:- You probably have a problem with backticks. Plz check it.